# How do you make a custom icon for the Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, inkscape

This is not specifically a programming question, but I find I keep having to look this process up in the midst of doing android programming. I'm sharing my answer below for the convenience of other android developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by reading [Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html).

It is best if you can use the standard icons that come with Android. They can be downloaded [here](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html). However, if you are like me, sometimes you need to make a custom icon. This is a short tutorial for how to do it.

I use Inkscape to make vector graphics but I imaging the process is similar for Illustrator.

In Inkscape:

**One**. Make 512x512 pixel document

(File > Document Properties > Custom size > Units=px)
The background should be transparent. (Alpha = 00)

**Two**. Make the image shape you want.

**Three**. Change the color and alpha settings (Object > Fill and Stroke)

For Holo Light icons:

Color: #333333
Enabled: 60% opacity (alpha = 153 in dec, #99 in hex)
Disabled: 30% opacity (alpha = 76 in dec, #4C in hex)

For Holo Dark icons:

Color: #FFFFFF
Enabled: 80% opacity (alpha = 204 in dec, #CC in hex)
Disabled: 30% opacity (alpha = 76 in dec, #4C in hex)

(The background in Inkscape defaults to white so your image may appear invisible for white icons. You could change it back to black after you are done exporting your bitmap images.)

**Four**. Save the file as svg for future editing. (File > Save As)

**Five**. Export png files at various densities to use in your Android app

(File > Export bitmap)
Make sure that "Page" is selected
Set the width and height to 32px for mdpi
Click "Browse" to select the folder and filename
Use .png for the filename extension.
Click export to save the image

**Six**. Repeat the process in step 5 for all of the sizes that you need.

The file names should all be the same, but put them each in differently named folders. The following list makes good folder names.

mdpi_32x32
hdpi_48x48
xhdpi_64x64
xxhdpi_96x96
xxxhdpi_128x128

You can copy the images to your app's drawable folders and you are ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```